# Implementing java gui login using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I am working on a java application which has a login form in a jframe. I have text fields and buttons in it.

The login button has an eventlistener which is an **inner-class** of the class that creates the login window.  When user presses the login button, the listener takes the values form the fields and passes it to a validator which validates it using a mysql database and returns true and false based on the input by user. Now based on the return value the listener updates the ui using the `if-else` statement. This whole thing is working is fine.

The problem is that when the validation is being carried out the gui cannot be used, because every thing is being done with a single thread. So for that time the `gui` is kind of freezed.
How can I use multithreading to avoid this problem and use other gui components while validation is carried out.

Comment: Take a look at [SwinWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're probably aware, you should never perform long running tasks within the Event Dispatching Thread, this makes you program look like its hung.

Equally, you should never create/modify any UI component outside the Event Dispatching Thread.

One of the simplest solutions would be to use a SwingWorker.  This allows you execute code in a background thread, but it will automatically resync it's results back the Event Dispatching Thread...

```
public class LoginForm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginForm();
    }

    public LoginForm() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JDialog frame = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Login", true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new LoginPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;
        private JButton okay;
        private JButton cancel;

        public LoginPane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            userNameField = new JTextField(15);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

            okay = new JButton("Login");
            cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

            JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            mainPane.add(new JLabel("User Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            mainPane.add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            mainPane.add(userNameField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            mainPane.add(passwordField, gbc);
            mainPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

            add(mainPane);

            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            buttonPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            buttonPane.add(okay);
            buttonPane.add(cancel);

            add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    userNameField.setEnabled(false);
                    passwordField.setEnabled(false);
                    okay.setEnabled(false);
                    cancel.setEnabled(false);
                    new LoginWorker(userNameField.getText(), passwordField.getPassword()).execute();
                }
            });

            cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(LoginPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });
        }

        public class LoginWorker extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Boolean> {

            private String userName;
            private char[] password;

            public LoginWorker(String userName, char[] password) {
                this.userName = userName;
                this.password = password;
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // Do you background work here, query the database, compare the values...
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                return Math.round((Math.random() * 1)) == 0 ? new Boolean(true) : new Boolean(false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                System.out.println("Done...");
                try {
                    if (get()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPane.this, "Login sucessful");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPane.this, "Login failed");
                    }
                    userNameField.setEnabled(true);
                    passwordField.setEnabled(true);
                    okay.setEnabled(true);
                    cancel.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information, in particular, [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Ok, I also looked at Observer patterns, is it possible to use this concept here? I think when the validation is completed the validator can notify the ui components. So is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  It depends on "how".  In the done method of the `LoginWorker`, I re-enable the fields and display an `JOptionPane`, you could call a method within the UI form as required.  I'd generally use an `interface` to link the form and the worker, as the worker really doesn't care about where the information is coming from or going to, just that the contract is meet

Comment: @Digvijay Yadav this answer is about logics, Observe doesn't matter, fly to moon too, have to accepting that all updates to the Swing GUI must be done on EDT, otherwise nothing happens, EDT is separate thread that don't know nor care that something is created / runs from/to Workers Thread

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads. The tricky bit is to make sure that any updates you need to do to the UI is done on the UI thread. There's a [SwingUtilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) helper class for this.

Eg.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        // do the background work...

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 // update the UI
             }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

You could also look into using a background [executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) if you want to manage the way threads are created.

```
ExecutorService backgroundExector = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

(so you'd have one of these for your app that was used from multiple places).

Answer (score 0):

On pressing "Login" (from the button listener), disable the button and start the login thread. This thread must connect the database and set some fields on the self or login component class, informing about the login success. Surround the login code with `try {} finally {}` and in the finally section, call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. Now, it the `Runnable` that this method takes as parameter, you can re-enable buttons, show either "ok" or "login failed" and do other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Well starting a new thread is relativly easy.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(Runnable r);
thread.start();
```

While r needs to implement Runnable and contain your code for checking the username/password with the sql library within `run()`.

```
new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
        // your sql-code goes here.
    }
};
```

The actual problem is synchronizing any variables that you need to access from both the listeners and your sql-code.

Synchronizing a variable is easy.

```
class example {
  private synchronized Integer mySyncInteger = new Integer();
}
```

After execution of your sql code I would simply trigger some function from the view (where you do your swing-work) like `swingClass.pushResult(Boolean)`. This function changes the view according to the result given. Be careful with updating the view from that function, because this is still working within the Thread you created.

Comment: But when should the ui component check for this variable, because earlier threads can be executed at later times based on scheduling by the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread that will do the communication with the database to validate the user and password. However, the UI update should only be done from the Event Dispatcher thread. You can do this by using the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` methods.

so your thread could be implemented like this:

```
public void run()
{
    // logic to validate user/password

    if(valid == true)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(/*Runnable to update the UI*/));
    }
}
```