# Is it possible to create a GUI in eclipse without the use of WindowsBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently a student and i have been given an assignment to make a POS system using Eclipse. So far from all my searches i haven't found any tutorial to create a GUI through eclipse through raw coding (i mean without the use of plugins such as windowsbuilder) so my question is, is there actually a way to use raw coding to create a GUI such as a login page for a POS system? Thank you for your time and your answers are very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, please do! Have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some ideas

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210003/implementing-java-gui-login-using-multithreading/14210970#14210970), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406367/resize-the-button-of-login-screen/33406533#33406533), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918865/login-and-logout-in-swing/15919516#15919516)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, thank you for your swift reply! I have checked ur examples and as im not a very experienced programmer (just started java programming on eclipse through college) I am wondering if the login panel will be able to fetch info from a notepad and verify if the user and password is correct then bring it onto the next page? is that possible? without the use of windowsbuilder. i stress on not using windowsbuilder because i want to understand how the codes work and also because my teacher hasnt gotten to that part so its kinda like cheating.

Comment: The general answer to your question is yes

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you :D ill do more research as to how I can take the data from a notepad i guess. TY again !

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, im sorry but i have one more question. If i did make a GUI with windowsBuilder will it be able to run on another eclipse without the plugin? what i mean is does the execution of the GUI will be needing the plugin or is it independent meaning without the plugin it will stil be able to perform its functions?

Comment: Yes, but WindowBuilder is nitrous for doing some very bad things, if you have the time, learning to build your UI's by hand will give you greater level of knowledge over how best to layout your UI's and your code.  Also , you might like to have a look [at Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use gui libraries to create your gui such as swing, swt, awt
The table gui with swing link below... You can do whatever you want

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaJTable.htm